# Should a view model contain a logger?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, mvvm

New to MVVM...and I am noticing our ViewModel's are doing the following:

1. They are handling their own exceptions
2. They are instantiating the log4net logger directly

**MY OPINION:**
In my opinion, we should create a static logging helper-class that wraps log4net and all objects should refer to that.  This way we can easily change-out the logging utility anytime we desire with minimal

Except in rare occasions, I don’t think model & view model objects (or objects like them) should trap or manage errors.  The only time we should trap an error (in a model of any type) is when we feel certain we cannot easily fix it, and therefore, we must handle it is as  gracefully and succinctly as we can.  And even then, we have to be careful not to use exceptions to manage the normal flow of logic (see example below).  We should really let the higher layers log & handle exceptions (i.e. the UI layer).  The only job of a model or view model should simply be that…to be a model or view model…mainly because other things will simply  clutter the code.  But also because I feel it creates better separation.  I would not put a logging utility in a model or view model any more than I would a Data Transfer Object (DTO).  And once I describe it that way…I think we can easily see why I feel that way.

An example of what I mean by handle normal flow of logic:

```
MealExpenses expenses = expenseReportDAO.getMeals(employee.Id)
expenses.ForEach(x => {
Try
{
   total += expenses.getTotal();
}
Catch(MealExpensesNotFound ex)
{
   total += getMealPerDiem();
}
})
```

...I'm sure you can see why the above examlpe is bad.

**SO MY QUESTION IS:**
Should a view model contain a logger? What should it do? What should it NOT do? What do you guys think?

Comment: Just a separate comment about your code: I wouldn't use an exception as you are doing for normal business logic.

Comment: @Fernando You are correct. However, I'm guessing you probably didn't read the paragraph as the example is already labeled as bad. It is meant to strengthen my argument against logging in the view model: the logic being that logging exceptions at this level gives rise to the temptation to use exceptions to manage the normal flow of logic. Which, as we all know, is bad. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ViewModel` should be a simple container of the data the view consumes and should have no behaviour that is not *directly* associated with the view (click handlers, for example). Even the behaviour it does have should delegate to the `Model`.

So, as a `ViewModel` should be very simple, it really shouldn't need to log anything. This is something that should be left to the application infrastructure.

Comment: I agree with your initial comment completely. However, are you also saying, "...the model should do logging?" Because I kinda disagree with that.

Comment: I guess my argument against putting logging inside a view model would be the view model can’t redirect to other pages or show errors in interesting ways (nor should it).  It should be what it is...simply...a view model.  And upper layers should do what they do best in this area.  Waddya think?

Comment: @PrisonerZERO - I agree with what you say about the responsibilities of a `ViewModel`. That was kinda my point, if not expressed exactly like that.

Comment: Kewl...then, when you have a minute, could you please update your answer to say 'application infrastructure' rather than model.  That way, folks won't get confused.  And thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why not. Usually, viewmodels are in the application assembly not in a library project. When you create library it may make sense to abstract away the logger, but in the GUI application there is no need to. The application will be dependent on the logger library anyway. Unless you plan to swap out loggers every week there is no need to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Sure a ViewModel can contain a Logger but just make sure its an interface so it can be mocked. You don't want your visual studio designer using an unmocked logger. IMO, a good time to use your favorite IoC container to inject that ILoggerService if you really want to do client side logging.